# rails 4 nested resource routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a routes file (Rails 4.0.4 App):

```
resources :products do
  resources :variants, except: :index
end
```

*rake routes* gives:

```
       product_variants POST   /products/:product_id/variants(.:format)             variants#create
    new_product_variant GET    /products/:product_id/variants/new(.:format)         variants#new
   edit_product_variant GET    /products/:product_id/variants/:id/edit(.:format)    variants#edit
        product_variant GET    /products/:product_id/variants/:id(.:format)         variants#show
                        PATCH  /products/:product_id/variants/:id(.:format)         variants#update
                        PUT    /products/:product_id/variants/:id(.:format)         variants#update
                        DELETE /products/:product_id/variants/:id(.:format)         variants#destroy
```

So as proposed I'm using

```
<%= form_for [@product, @variant] do |f| %>
```

but this generates (note the URL):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/variants/1" class="edit_variant" id="edit_variant_1" method="post">
```

And I get (of course) the routing error saying no route matches with PATCH /variants/1

Same strange behaviour when I redirect to in an Api Controller living namespaced under *api/*:

```
redirect_to [:api, @product, @variant]
```

Got me: *no route matches with /api/variants/1*

So:

- I checked all routes
- I know how to nest resources and namespace them
- I thought I know how to generate the URL's ;-)

Somehow the @products is ignored when generating the urls

Has anyone a clue where to look any further?

Comment: You can confirm that the `@product` variable is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your variants controller.  Are you instantiating @product?

It may be helpful to post the code for controller too.

Hope this helps!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem really lies in the different controllers. I somehow instantiated @products in a before action, but obviously did it wrong.

Seems to be a leck of energy drink problem. thanks for pointing me to the right solution!